# Is it possible to add a Manifest file to a project in VS2005 Academic Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, manifest, c#-2.0

I'm working on a really old program for my employer that requires a manifest file. Unfortunately the project was developed in .Net 2.0 on VS 2005 (Academic Edition) and migrating/updating to a newer... whatever would be time consuming and the really not worth it.

I've found ways to add a manifest file to a .exe manually (which is kind of a headache and I would prefer to avoid that route if that is at all possible for me to automatically include a manifest file into the application? I've found a few things on it but the options they reference seem to be missing from the Academic Edition.

I've seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229(v=vs.80).aspx) direction but there doesn't seem to be a manifest tool node (or I'm doing it wrong, could be either one). I found some images the closest I could get was this:

[image]

And it's missing the Manifest node that was referenced.

Is this possible to do with Academic Edition, or am I just hosed into having to do it the Open .exe in VS/add as a resource method? If I have to do it that way, that's fine but if there's a better way then I would prefer the better way.

Comment: Why on Earth are you using VS2005 with an Academic license?  People don't go to school for 9 years.  Just update your VS version.

Comment: Because it was the only version of VS2005 my employer has available.

Comment: You are not using a licensed version of VS2005.  An academic license automatically expires when a student leaves the institute that bought the license.  You'll need to inform your employer that he's violating a legal contract and is liable for damages that include any profits gained from such illegal usage.